# how do i create a RXJS pausable data flow that doesnt reset on each resume?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

i have tried out the documented example for RXJS pausable and while it pauses ok it resets on resume. how do i modify the example below to have my stream resume from where i paused it rather than reset?

```
  var pauser = new Rx.Subject();

  var source = Rx.Observable
    .interval(1000)
    .timeInterval()
    .pausable(pauser);

  var subscription = source.subscribe(
    function (x) {
        $("#result").append('Next: ' + JSON.stringify(x) + '<br>');
    },
    function (err) {
        $("#result").append('Error: ' + err);
    },
    function () {
        $("#result").append('Completed');
    });


  pauser.onNext(true);

  var paused = false;
  $("#result").click(function() { 
    $(this).append("mouse clicked");
    paused = (paused === false) ? true : false;
    pauser.onNext(paused);
  });
```

this is giving me the following output:

```
Next: {"value":0,"interval":1002}
Next: {"value":1,"interval":1000}
Next: {"value":2,"interval":999}
mouse clicked
mouse clicked
Next: {"value":0,"interval":1001}
Next: {"value":1,"interval":999}
Next: {"value":2,"interval":1000}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the `pausable` documentation, `pausable` is to be used on hot sources.

One way to make a source hot is to use `share`. However, this will not work as is in conjunction with `pausable` because `share` will disconnect its source when it has no subscribers, which will happen when you will pause.

So here are two ways to make this work. One is to use `share` and keep a dummy subscriber so that `share` never disconnects from its source as there will always be at least one subscriber. The second way is to use `publish`, and `connect` the observable once all the wiring has been made.

[Example 1](http://jsfiddle.net/ay5eLhop/2/) with dummy subscriber:

```
  var pauser = new Rx.Subject();

  function noop(){}

  var source = Rx.Observable
    .interval(1000)
    .timeInterval()
    .share();

  var pausableSource = source.pausable(pauser);

  var subscription = pausableSource.subscribe(
    function (x) {
        $("#ta_result").append('Next: ' + JSON.stringify(x) + '<br>');
    },
    function (err) {
        $("#ta_result").append('Error: ' + err);
    },
    function () {
        $("#ta_result").append('Completed');
    });
  source.subscribe(noop);

  pauser.onNext(false);

  var paused = false;
  $("#result").click(function() { 
    $("#ta_change").append("mouse clicked\n");
    paused = !paused;
    pauser.onNext(paused);
  });
```

[Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/h0eLcy53/) with `connect`:

```
  var pauser = new Rx.Subject();

  var source = Rx.Observable
    .interval(1000)
    .timeInterval()
    .publish();

  var pausableSource = source.pausable(pauser);
//  source.subscribe(function(){});

  var subscription = pausableSource.subscribe(
    function (x) {
        $("#ta_result").append('Next: ' + JSON.stringify(x) + '<br>');
    },
    function (err) {
        $("#ta_result").append('Error: ' + err);
    },
    function () {
        $("#ta_result").append('Completed');
    });

  source.connect();
  pauser.onNext(false);

  var paused = false;
  $("#result").click(function() { 
    $("#ta_change").append("mouse clicked\n");
    paused = !paused;
    pauser.onNext(paused);
  });
```

Comment: i have tried this (without fully understanding what the share does yet) but the share() is having no effect. the output is the same as above? i.e. reset.

Comment: my apologies, there are a few non-obvious nuances (in which in addition to hot and cold observables, you need to add the notion of connectable observable, I'll skip the explanations for this time). I'll post two work-arounds.

Comment: problem solved... and i understand hot/cold observables a lot more than when is started. i am very grateful for your time in helping me get started with this. many thanks.